# Question 11.12 introduction to analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying number theory from Tom M Apostol and could not solve this problem on page 247 of textbook. So, asking for help here.

Question : [image]

I have problem in only the part where I have to prove that F(s) is to be proved non zero.

Attempt:I proved that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ f(n) } { n^s} $ × $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ f^{-1}(n) }{ n^s} $  =  1. So, to prove that F(s) is never zero, I need to prove that $f^{-1}$ is convergent. But I am unable to do so.

Can you please tell how to complete the proof?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-1} (n)$,  Note that $f(x) = 0, 1$. In particular, if $f(2) = 0$, what is $ f^{-1} (2)$?

Comment: Is $\lambda(n) = (-1)^{\Omega(n)}$? In any case, $F(s)$ will have a convergent Euler product, which (by definition) means that it does not equal $0$ unless an individual factor equals $0$.

Comment: @Calvin  Lin  $f^{-1} (n) = f(n) \mu(n) $ as f is completely multiplicative here.

Comment: @Greg Martin $\lambda (n) $ is lioville function.

Comment: Since $f^{-1}(n) = \mu(n)f(n)$, it follows that $\lvert f^{-1}(n)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f(n)\rvert$ for all $n$. Thus the absolute convergence of the $F(s)$ series implies the absolute convergence of the series of $1/F(s)$.